# Docker-Compose: how to configure container with VPN Split-Tunnelling?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I need the network traffic of a Docker service to pass through VPN,
and also to be able to reach other containers outside VPN from that container.

I'm able to get the first requirement working by configuring an `OpenConnect` service

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  open-connect:
    container_name: open-connect
    image: open-connect
    build:
      dockerfile: Docker/OpenConnect.Dockerfile
      context: .
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - VPN_PROTOCOL
      - VPN_HOST
      - VPN_PORT
      - VPN_USERNAME
      - VPN_PASSWORD
```

and making the traffic of the other service pass through it via `network_mode: container:open-connect`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  vpn-client:
    container_name: vpn-client
    image: vpn-client
    build:
      dockerfile: Docker/Busybox.Dockerfile
      context: ..
    network_mode: container:open-connect
  service-a:
    hostname: service-a
    container_name: service-a
    image: service-a
    build:
      dockerfile: Docker/Busybox.Dockerfile
      context: ..
    networks:
      backend:
  service-b:
    hostname: service-b
    container_name: service-b
    image: service-b
    build:
      dockerfile: Docker/Busybox.Dockerfile
      context: ..
    networks:
      backend:

networks:
  backend:
```

The problem is that only `service-a` and `service-b` are able to ping each other.

From `vpn-client` it is not possible to reach neither `service-a` or `service-b`,
similarly in the reverse way.

I cannot combine `network-mode` and `networks` in the `vpn-client` service:

```
ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined
```

What else can be done to make the `vpn-client`, `service-a` and `service-b` mutually reachable without being all of them behind `VPN network`?

---

**Update**

**VPN Split Tunnelling**

Based on some resources I found, the solution seems to be the
configuration of VPN with `split-tunnelling` instead of `full-tunneling`.

- https://cybernews.com/what-is-vpn/split-tunneling/
- https://gist.github.com/stefancocora/686bbce938f27ef72649a181e7bd0158
- https://gist.github.com/jagtesh/5531300

So the question becomes: how to configure VPN split-tunnelling in the `open-connect` service?